# image hover effect issue

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to do an effect that when I pass the mouse over on a picture I want to show a black box that appears closing stay only a square in the middle where I want to place an icon of a search icon.

I found a tutorial that explains how to do this, but it explains very lightly.

I am having a problem because I wanted my picture have width:155px; and height:140px;.

But When I give this width and height values in `.view {}` the square in the middle that I do not want to turn it black disappears, and I want that square visible to put icon search there.
Maybe I´m not explained myself well, but I think with the jsFiddle you can understand my problem. I wish you could help me, any help is welcome!

**My fiddle to better understand:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/cQL4S/

**My html:**

```
<div class="view second-effect">
    <img src="images/image1.jpg" />
    <div class="mask">
       <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My css:**

```
.view {
   width: 225px;
   height: 225px;
   margin: 10px;
   float: left;
   border: 5px solid #fff;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
   cursor: default;
}
.view .mask, .view .content {
    width: 225px;
   height: 225px;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}
.view a.info {
   background:url(../img/link.png) center no-repeat;
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding:0;
   text-indent:-9999px;
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
}


.second-effect .mask {
   opacity: 0;
   overflow:visible;
   border:0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.second-effect a.info {
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    opacity:0;
   -moz-transform:scale(0,0);
   -webkit-transform:scale(0,0);
   -o-transform:scale(0,0);
   -ms-transform:scale(0,0);
   transform:scale(0,0);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s 0.1s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s 0.1s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: -o-transform 0.2s 0.1s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.2s 0.1s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform 0.2s 0.1s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.second-effect:hover .mask {
   opacity: 1;
   border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.second-effect:hover a.info {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);
    -o-transform:scale(1,1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1,1);
    transform:scale(1,1);
    -moz-transition-delay:0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:0.3s;
    -o-transition-delay:0.3s;
    -ms-transition-delay:0.3s;
    transition-delay:0.3s;
}
```

**My jsfiddle with the problem:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/cQL4S/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the icon is wrong. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/cQL4S/5/

```
.second-effect a.info {
  top: 20px;
}
```

I made the background red so you can see.

Answer (score 2):

When you resize the container, you will have to resize the hover as well. The hover has a border of 100px. This is more than the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/cQL4S/3/

```
   .second-effect:hover .mask {
     border:40px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   }
```

Also becourse you're new size is not a square, the border is not a square.

Comment: You are right. And can make square adding     border-right-width: 47px;
    border-left-width: 47px;
}

Comment: I've been here lots of time to look and I could not understand it, thank you really!

Comment: I´m trying to put a icon font in the middle square but I´m having some problems centering the icon. If you can see if its ok my jsfiddle with icon will be great... http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/cQL4S/5/

Comment: Remove the text-indent: -9999px;